# Entity Framework - read an object, Include() everything, then set object.Id = 0

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I have a situation where I want to create a new record that is identical to an existing record, including all its 1:1 and 1:many relationships, except change 1 column.

So, can I somehow read an object, calling `Include()` for every property, then set the `Id` property to 0, change the 1 column, and then `Add()` it to the `DbSet` and save it? And have all the included properties get copied across?

I tried doing this two different ways and got an exception. But it seems to me logically this should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One simple way to make a deep copy is Automapper, however you will need to re-bind any references, related entities that reference existing rows rather than clone as new rows.

So for instance if we have a Class A that contains a collection of Class Bs, and a reference to a Class C: We want a new clone of Class A with a new set of Class Bs, but referncing the same Class C instance: Think Order, OrderItems, and OrderStatus. A new order has a new collection of order items, but references, not owns a status.

```
var config = new Mapper.MappingConfiguration(cfg => 
{
     cfg.CreateMap<ClassA, ClassA>()
         .ForMember(src => src.C, opt => opt.Ignore());
     cfg.CreateMap<ClassB, ClassB>();
};
var mapper = config.CreateMapper();

var classA = _context.ClassAs
    .Include(a => a.Bs)
    .Include(a => a.C)
    .Single(a => a.Id == aId);

var newA = mapper.Map<ClassA>(classA);

newA.C = classA.C; // Reference the same C.

// Update any values in newA and/or newA.Bs...

_context.As.Add(newA);
_context.SaveChanges();
```

We configure the mapper to ignore any referenced entities and clone any related entities we want new copies of. We can then edit those copies and add them to the context. As long as Automapper knows to expect ClassAs & ClassBs, when it is going through the target type it will search and construct new instances, copying values across. It does not matter if the PKs of these entities are set or not, you could configure the mapper to ignore them if you have logic that checks for a default PK for new rows. It is the fact that these entities aren't tracked which means EF will treat them as new. This is why we need to re-reference related entities (ClassC) rather than clone it. We don't want EF to insert a new copy, but just associate the new record with the existing tracked reference.